# Using id twice in jQuery function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Help, please, deal with jQuery:

The radio buttons 1 and 2 use a picture with the same id, but they should open blocks with different text. http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/65/

In my case, button 1 does not load the picture, and the second one works fine. What can be the problem and how to fix it?

I've tried to make it with classes, but it doesn't work too.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.radiobuttons').change(function() {
    if ($('#item1').prop('checked')) {
        $('.img2, #text1').show();
    } else {
        $('.img2, #text1').hide();
    }
      if ($('#item2').prop('checked')) {
        $('.img2, #text2').show();
    } else {
        $('.img2, #text2').hide();
    }
     if ($('#item3').prop('checked')) {
        $('.img3, #text3').show();
    } else {
        $('.img3, #text3').hide();
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img2" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png" alt=""></div>
 <div class="img3" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/static/images/simple-image-resizer-128x128.png" alt=""></div>

        

<form class="radiobuttons">
  <p id="desc1"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item1" value="1">Text 1</p>
  <p id="desc2"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item2" value="1">Text 2</p>
  <p id="desc3"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item3" value="1">Text 3</p>
</form>

    <div class="text" id="text1" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text1</div>
    <div class="text" id="text2" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text2</div>
    <div class="text" id="text3" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text3</div>
```

Comment: You can not have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: @epascarello here is with classes - http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/27/ Still not solved

Comment: check your code, item1' => select  .img2,  I think it should be img1

Comment: @VictorXie Sorry, but no. I've edited the code in post to make it more clear

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Will you try this way?

http://jsfiddle.net/54tsowq7/60/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image-wrap">
        <div class="image">
            <div class="img" id="pic1"><img src="img/main_v3-38.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="img" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="http://images.math.cnrs.fr/IMG/png/section8-image.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="img" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/static/images/simple-image-resizer-128x128.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
<form class="radiobuttons">
  <p id="desc1"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item1" value="1" data-picid="pic2" data-textid="text1">Text 1</p>
  <p id="desc2"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item2" value="1" data-picid="pic2" data-textid="text2">Text 2</p>
  <p id="desc3"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item3" value="1" data-picid="pic3" data-textid="text3">Text 3</p>

</form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text" id="text1" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text1</div>
    <div class="text" id="text2" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text2</div>
    <div class="text" id="text3" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text3</div>
<div class="image-wrap">
        <div class="image">
            <div class="img" id="pic1"><img src="img/main_v3-38.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="img" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="img/main_v3-41.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="img" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="img/main_v3-44.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
   $('.text, .img').hide();
   var $pic = $('#'+$(this).data('picid'));
   var $text = $('#'+$(this).data('textid'));   
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
     $pic.show();
     $text.show();
   }else{  
     $pic.hide();
     $text.hide();
   };
});
});
```

Comment: @Anton pls see my answer, you were very close

Answer (score -1):

I know what is happening..

It's that you're going into your first if condition to show the img2.

And THEN, you're going into the 2nd if/else condition ALSO which immediately will hide the img2.

You can add returns in each of the if statements

```
  YOU'RE GOING IN HERE.. GOOD
 if ($('#item1').prop('checked')) {
    $('.img2, #text1').show();
} else {
    $('.img2, #text1').hide();
}

 THEN YOU'RE GOING INTO THIS 'ELSE' AFTER...  BAD
  if ($('#item2').prop('checked')) {
    $('.img2, #text2').show();
} else {
    $('.img2, #text2').hide();
}
```

If you have another level of ELSEs here to ensure that only 1 IF/ELSE is ever used, your logic should work correct.

Comment: this is the correct solution to the exact issue to the code the OP was asking.  this should not have any downvotes.

Answer (score -1):

I think to use `class`.

I hope this code helps you.

https://codepen.io/seunggabi/pen/rZJgbP

Answer (score -2):

Since your images, radios and text all use same indexing you can simplify this by making sure they all have common classes. Using unique classes for each item is not common.

Then you can use [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to show/hide the matching components

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $radios = $('.radiobuttons :radio').change(function() {
    var idx = $radios.index(this);
    $('.text').hide().eq(idx).show();
    $('.img').hide().eq(idx).show()
  });
  // trigger first radio on page load
  $radios.first().prop('checked',true).change()


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-wrap">
      <div class="image">
        <div class="img" id="pic1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image+1" alt=""></div>
        <div class="img" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image+2" alt=""></div>
        <div class="img" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image+3" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <form class="radiobuttons">
        <p id="desc1"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item1" value="1">Text 1</p>
        <p id="desc2"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item2" value="1">Text 2</p>
        <p id="desc3"><input type="radio" name="item1" id="item3" value="1">Text 3</p>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text" id="text1" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text1</div>
  <div class="text" id="text2" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text2</div>
  <div class="text" id="text3" style='display:none'>Lorem Ipsum Text3</div>
  <div class="image-wrap">
    <div class="image">
      <div class="img1" id="pic1"><img src="img/main_v3-38.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img2" id="pic2" style='display:none'><img src="img/main_v3-41.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="img3" id="pic3" style='display:none'><img src="img/main_v3-44.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```